# Make data persist in form using mongodb node express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

Hi I can connect to and store to mongodb using mlab but I can't get the data in the form to remain on refresh. 
The form takes in user input from input-boxes.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If what you want to achieve is to get some particular form data after making a new get request, then you will need to provide some information in request about the form data you need. If the application is simple, cant you just use local storage to store the data locally?....another overkill method might be maintaining sessions and using cookies etc to track requests and update form data accordingly.

Comment: If so,the two requests cannot be linked by default. If you want to know whether the request comes from a client that previously requested something and respond accordingly you will have to use express-session.

Comment: What that means is all you would have in you DB is a single document that is accessed/updated by any client ..right? If so then read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If being able to get the same form data for all the requests (no matter where they are made from)is what you want, then a possible workaround could be as follows:

1) Store the initial form data(probably empty) in the database, get the ObjectId and hard code it in your code, this way all the updates would be made to that specific MongoDB document only.

2) The form route (below one) should do nothing except for serving the file which has the form

```
app.get('/form1', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public');
//record.find({"_id": ObjectId("MLAB ID")})......dont do this


});
```

3)  There should be another route that sends form data

```
app.get('/getdata', function(req, res) {
        record.find({"_id": ObjectId("MLAB ID")}, function(err, doc) {
            res.send(doc)
        })
    });
```

4)The static file that you send to the client should have a javascript function such that it asks for the form data as soon as your window loads and then sets the value of input elements from that data recieved:

```
 window.onload = function() {
        //make a GET request to /getdata to get form data....store it in obj
        //then set the input values
       document.getElementById("yourchoice").value = obj.yourchoice;
        //and set the value of other input fields ....in similar amnner

    }
```

5) The POST request you make should update that specific document( findOneAndUpdate?? )

**Disadvantage of this method:**

For one operation we request a file from server and then another request to get form data, so two requests for one operation, since we cannot use both res.sendFile() and res.json() together...one way to get around this is to hide the form data as well in the HTML document using a template engine. More about this can easily be found. Anyways the above method does solve your purpose.

I hope I correctly understood the problem statement.

Happy coding!!

**Edit:**Although the above mentioned points are explainatory, I have written a sample snippet at : https://pastebin.com/AvgVyx7b

It works perfectly fine

Comment: No need to be sorry :-) Things can sometimes get confusing .   .........As far as I know , there is no way the input elements can hold data even after page refresh. The nearest you can get to is to repopulate the input elements with the data requested from the server after the page refresh. Wont that satisfy?

Comment: The other way out of this is to use template engine on the server and form html pages on the server such that the default values in the input element tag are set and then the file is sent . But even for that the client will first have to click a button/ cause some action to save data on the server which can be retrieved later.

Comment: The points mentioned in the answer will help you in achieving that, in any case i will try to provide a more detailed sample code asap..maybe tomorrow...until then try implementing these steps.

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can have a look . Cheers!!